# How to fix exception on: cimg(cv::Mat)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I'm developing an emotion detecting software using **C++** and **opencv** library.

When the execution reaches this line:

```
cv_image<bgr_pixel> cimg(original);
```

there is a VisualStudio exeption:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFC54F9A839 in Emotion.exe: Microsoft C ++ exception: dlib :: fatal error at memory location 0x00000064B36F7270.

See the entire function:

```
CvCapture* cap = cvCaptureFromAVI("sample.avi");
IplImage* frame2;
cv::Mat original;
while(1)
{
    frame2 = cvQueryFrame(cap);
    cv::Mat frame = cv::cvarrToMat(frame2);
    original = frame.clone();
    cv_image<bgr_pixel> cimg(original); //exception here
    ...
}
```

I suppose that problem is caused by `original`.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/620402/10933809

Comment: @oblivion all present objects are returned by function.

Comment: my guess was original isn't initialized correctly. You may check it with your debugger